# Showing the MaterialDatePicker when clicking into the Material Outlined Text Field

Tags: android, datepicker, android-edittext, dialog, material-components-android

I am working on a small app where the user can start an activity.
By doing that, a text input shall is shown where todays date is set by default.

When clicking into the text field, the MaterialDatePicker shall be shown as dialog.

I have successfully implemented that the MaterialDatePicker shows up when clicking on a button, but I cannot find a sololution to show the dialog instead of the Android standard android keyboard.

Any advises on that?

**Activity XML:**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/edtStartWearLensDate"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:hint="@string/txtLabelWearSelectStartDate"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtLabelStartWearLensID">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**Activity:**

On Create:

```
edtStartWearLensDate = findViewById(R.id.edtStartWearLensDate);
edtStartWearLensDate.setOnClickListener(view -> onEdtStartWearLensDateClick());
```

On Click into the text field

```
private void onEdtStartWearLensDateClick() {
        showDatePickerDialog();
}
```

Method to show dialog (works when calling from a Button on click listener)

```
private void showDatePickerDialog(){
        MaterialDatePicker.Builder builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker();

        builder.setTitleText("Select start date");
        builder.setSelection(MaterialDatePicker.todayInUtcMilliseconds());

        final MaterialDatePicker materialDatePicker = builder.build();

        materialDatePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DATE_PICKER");

        materialDatePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(new MaterialPickerOnPositiveButtonClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPositiveButtonClick(Object selection) {
                edtStartWearLensDate.getEditText().setText(materialDatePicker.getHeaderText());
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the `clickable` and `focusable` properties to `true` in the `TextInputEditText`:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/text_input_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:clickable="true"/>
```

And call the `setOnClickListener` method on it:

```
findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.text_input_edit_text).setOnClickListener(view -> onEdtStartWearLensDateClick())
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing me on the right track! 

Following did the trick: 
Call the setOnClickListener method on the TextInputEditText instead of the TextInputLayout. 
Set "focusable" of the TextInputEditText to "false" and "clickable" to "true".